# C - Passing an array to a method

Tags: c, pointers

I have a problem when passing an array to a function

For some reason it seems that half of its elements are missing, and replaced with some other stuff.

When I iterate the array before calling the method, I get this output:

```
    Votes: 2387
    Votes: 2105
    Votes: 1230
    Votes: 1132
    Votes: 2587
    Votes: 559
```

Inside the method I get this:

```
    Votes: 2387
    Votes: 1230
    Votes: 2587
    Votes: 1
    Votes: 6689632
    Votes: 4199349
```

It seems that it goes 2 by 2 instead of adding 1 to the iterator, maybe I am not using pointers the right way.

This is the code, maybe you can see what is wrong:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    void method(int *options[], int *numberOfOptions);

    main() {

        int options[6] = {2387,2105,1230,1132,2587,559};

        int size = 6;

        int i = 0;

        while (i < size) {


            printf("Votes: %d \n",options[i]);

            i++;        

        }

        method (&options,&size);

    }

    void method(int *options[], int *numberOfOptions) {

        int i = 0;

        while (i < *numberOfOptions) {

            int optionVotes = options[i];

            printf("Votes: %d \n",optionVotes);     


            i++;        
        }


    }
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I've done C but I think an array doesn't need the & to be passed to a function.

Comment: Your `options` parameter is an array of int pointers, not a pointer to int. Get rid of the `[]` after `options`.

Comment: You'll want to replace `int *options[]` with `int *options` or `int options[]` in function prototype and definition, and replace call with `method (options,&size);`.

Comment: The comments above are true, but besides you hardly need to pass the array size as int*, unless you change it in your function.  Pass it as int.

Comment: The solution of your problem is in the title. Read about how to pass an array to a function in C.

Comment: Not related to your question, but it's `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` (or variants on char *argv[]). ( Unless you are writing for an embedded system.)  Throw away the book that gets that wrong.  It's either full of mistakes or a C++ book.

Comment: @leojg: Why did you ignore the diagnostic messages that the compiler gave you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does issue warnings about your array pointer passing. You are also unnecessarily passing the array size as a pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void method(int *options, int numberOfOptions);

main() {
    int options[6] = {2387,2105,1230,1132,2587,559};
    int size = 6;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < size) {
        printf("Votes: %d \n",options[i]);
        i++;        
    }
    method (options,size);
}

void method(int *options, int numberOfOptions) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < numberOfOptions) {
        int optionVotes = options[i];
        printf("Votes: %d \n",optionVotes);     
        i++;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw those warnings but I did not really understand what they were. Also I thought that by passing them as pointers It would  be more efficient. I dont understand how it work yet. Thanks!

Comment: It would help if this answer explained what's going on ... pointers on the OP's machine are twice as large as ints, so each pair of ints is being fetched as if it were one pointer, and then truncated back to an int when assigned to `optionVotes`.

Comment: The argument (int *options) can be used either as a pointer to one integer or to an array. The first (or only) element can be accessed with *options or options[0]. It is usual to pass a value rather than a pointer, unless you want the value modified, or to save space on the stack, or inefficient code. That's why the first argument is passed by reference. The second argument should be passed by value to prevent accidentally altering it and although it can be modified by the function, it's a different variable on the function's stack that is discarded on return.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, your sample code gives the output you want when compiled using MinGW (GCC 4.8.1), so I am not replicating your issue.

As far as I can see, there is 1 clear problem, that is in this line

```
printf("Votes: %d \n",optionVotes);
```

which should be:

```
printf("Votes: %d \n",&optionVotes);
```

since the `optionVotes` is an `int`, you need the reference to that int. In `main` function, `options[i]` is interpreted as `(options+1)`, and since `options` itself is a pointer, that works as expected without that.

Comment: On your mingw system, ints and pointers are the same size, unlike on the OP's system. And `&optionVotes` is completely wrong. And "options[i] is interpreted as (options+1)" is also wrong -- `options[i]` is the same as `*(options + i)`. Please don't dispense completely wrong information.